# ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with a value out of range for a double-precision float

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorboard

when I use TensorBoard to record the `adaptive learning rate` of a neural network, I use this code:

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir)
with summary_writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar('metrics/learning rate', data=float(model.optimizer._hyper['learning_rate']), step=epoch)
```

The problem is the `model.optimizer._hyper['learning_rate']` goes all the way up to an extremely large number, 4.07e+38. Then, the program yields an error:

```
ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with a value out of range for a double-precision float.
```

How can I fix it?